# Possible application to backboard in shower

Tags: shower, mold, backer-board

I had a mild mold issue and as I tore the bottom of the window frame (in the middle of the back shower wall) I found more and more damp wood. Noticing there was plywood instead of cement board. I tore out the plywood and then the rusted out metal panels behind that to uncover the wall boards; which are were used on the walls throughout the house where plaster and metal mesh (chicken wire) were applied over it (not in the shower though).

[image: picture]

So my question is, from the picture those back boards are damp looking but they are in good condition, is there something I should apply to them before covering then with cement board?

[image]

Comment: Is that actually a shower? It has a window. Really, drywall has no business around a tub in either case.

Comment: @isherwood There is no drywall, well except about the top 2' of the wall I meant sheet rock is what I will be reinstalling. That had plastic, fiberglass, or whatever it is around the shower down to the tub. Added a before pic.

Comment: *Sheetrock* is a brand of drywall, which is why I edited it out of your post. Perhaps you meant cement board?

Comment: @isherwood not knowing you had edited the post I thought I errored in using the word drywall. I do mean cement board when using the word sheet rock, which I am sure must people I have come across have used to mean the same thing; more so than someone referring to drywall.

Comment: "Sheet rock" is never used to refer to cement board. It's an almost universal synonym for gypsum panels, or drywall. I think you're making an assumption based on not having been corrected by anyone before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would let that dry the best you can, heat or fan...once that is done, paint it with kilz or similar and, of course, wait for that to dry, then install backer board up the wall. The reason I would paint the framing is to inhibit any growth of spores you can't get to die completely, therefore sealing them in and causing them to die. Some people seal it, others don't. I know a few people who bleach it and be done with it. Some use a mold/mildew converter, and some paint it with regular paint.

Comment: Thanks. I have had a fan on it for a couple hours and will do for maybe a few more hours, but it's the only shower in the house so really don't have time to apply Kilz. Had to spend money on a wall kit, since the back was crappy anyways. Just going to cover the window for now so I don't have to deal with water getting between window and wall, at least until I save up for a whole remodel of the bathroom.

Comment: Jeff, you haven't offered any reasoning for taking the time and expense to paint the framing. Please do so to make this a better answer.

Comment: I suggest, if you want to use the shower during the repair, to tack some plastic sheeting over the walls and draped into the tub to keep water off. Then dry it in between your use. Once it is dry, keep the plastic and paint it with the kilz, and continue as described. This way it will last. If you plan to do a full remodel in the near future, I would still use the kilz to seal the framing. You don't want to have to do that major of a job in the future. You could also do a half wall of the backer board and wet drywall the rest of the way. But I would prep as if you were doing a full remodel now